# 6to5 es6 class, new Date() triggers maximum callstack exceeded

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing an ES6 class using the 6to5 compiler. I have a pretty basic class which calls `new Date()` in a setter function and unfortunately results in a `maximum callstack exceeded` Chrome exception, and `too much recursion` in FireFox.

I'm not sure what's wrong with the following pattern, but calling `new Date()` is the cause of the exception:

```
class DateTime {
  constructor() {
    this.active = null
  }

  set active() {
    this.active = new Date()
  }

  get active() {
    return this.active
  }

}

new DateTime()
```

Comment: Can you maybe post the compiled code?

Comment: @Bergi I figured it out and answered. I'm new to ES6, this is probably a common mistake for beginners.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I should've seen that. Assigning to the self same property in a setter was a common mistake in ES5 as well :-)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the property `this.active` was actually a self reference to the setter method. The corrected code is the following:

```
  class DateTime {
    constructor() {
      this._active = null
    }

    set active( date ) {
      this._active = new Date( date || Date.now() )
    }

    get active() {
      return this._active
    }

    toString() {
      return this._active.toString()
    }

  }

 new DateTime()
```

Basically, *assigning* `this.active` inside the setter in the ES6 context will call the setter again before the property can be assigned. When the setter is called again, this becomes a recursive event.

Comment: Not necessarily *using* it, but *assiging* to it - notice the `=` in `this.active = …` :-)

Comment: Good call, updated my post. Thanks, I hadn't used classes in the ES5 context, I suppose it was more straightforward that collisions would occur when using Constructors because you could _see_ the exact properties on `this` in plain sight. If that makes sense.

Comment: Oh, creating infinite recursion was as easy as `var obj = {set active(x) { this.active = x; }}; obj.active = 0;` ;-)

Comment: Hah, apparently I missed that wave ;-)